# Why my app is not getting installed in android 12 or above?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

This is my manifest please can anyone check that where i have not included `android:manifet` i almost added everywhere this attribute but still not getting installed in android 12 and while uploading on play store it gives this errror = "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher."

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yash.earnfun">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".SketchApplication"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginnedmainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ReferActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

        <activity
            android:name=".BonusActivity"
            android:exported="true"
                            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ProfileActivity"
            android:exported="true" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

        <activity
            android:name=".RedeemActivity"
            android:exported="true" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />


        <activity
            android:name=".Redeem1Activity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Refer1Activity"
            android:exported="true" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

        <activity
            android:name=".EEarnActivity"
            android:exported="true" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

        <activity
            android:name=".PhoneActivity"
            android:exported="true" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SpinActivity"
            android:exported="true" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

        <activity
            android:name=".NameActivity"
            android:exported="true" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

        <activity
            android:name=".RedeemHActivity"
            android:exported="true" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".NotFonActivity"
            android:exported="true" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Spin2Activity"
            android:exported="true" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".PaymentActivity"
            android:exported="true" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />


        <activity
            android:name=".DebugActivity"
            android:exported="true" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.yash.earnfun.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="100" />

        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService"
            android:exported="false">

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />


            <meta-data              android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />

            <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />

        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">

            <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

<provider
        android:name="com.startapp.sdk.adsbase.StartAppInitProvider"
        android:authorities="APP_ID.startappinitprovider"
        android:exported="false" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.startapp.sdk.adsbase.consent.ConsentActivity"
        android:exported="true" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.startapp.sdk.ads.list3d.List3DActivity"
        android:exported="true" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.startapp.sdk.adsbase.activities.OverlayActivity"
        android:exported="true" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.startapp.sdk.adsbase.activities.FullScreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
        android:exported="true" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme"/>

        <service android:name="com.startapp.sdk.adsbase.InfoEventService" 
        android:exported="true"  />

    <service
        android:name="com.startapp.sdk.adsbase.PeriodicJobService"
        android:exported="true" 
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

    <receiver android:name="com.startapp.sdk.adsbase.remoteconfig.BootCompleteListener">
     android:exported="true" 

      <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried to add `android:exported` to every component but then also this error is coming

Comment: Please fix your formatting, it's difficult to read. Also, you missed adding exported attribute to `AdsActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Your activities should look like this in your manifest:

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.project.class.NonMainActivity"/>
    
    <activity
        android:name="com.project.class.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Note how the android:export tag is only on the main activity and the intent-filter is also inside of the main activity block.